# Pass information into URL on refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, stylesheet

I'm writing a JQuery submission form validator, and every time I press the submit button my page reloads.  The problem is that every time I loaded the page, I was passing information into the URL that told it which stylesheet to use.  Is there a way I can tell the page to use that same URL (including the concatenated information) when it reloads?

How can I pass information into the page URL when I click the submit button and it reloads?

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What you probably want to do is prevent the default submit event, use AJAX and do the logic in JavaScript.

Comment: I'm extremely new to javascript and jquery... I'm in a class that tries to teach each one in a single week.  In short, it doesn't work.

What do you mean prevent the default submit event?

Comment: I mean [preventdefault](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), and [ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `window.location` property coming and going:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(evt){
    evt.preventDefault();  // prevent normal submit mechanism
    window.location = window.location;   // redirect to current URL
});
```

Basically, when the user clicks the submit button, the event bubbles up to the form, which submits.  If nothing interferes with this mechanism, the browser will submit the form using the form's `action` attribute.  If the `action` attribute is absent, it will use the URL of the current page.

The code above intercepts the form submission, and substitutes your own code.  Note that we could also intercept the button press (`$('button').on('click')`), but this is generally safer because it covers other ways that a form can get submitted, such as pressing enter on a default field.

To redirect the browser to any URL, all you have to do is set `window.location`.  That property also stores the *current* URL, so setting it to itself, in essence, simply reloads the page.  Of course if you needed to modify the URL, you could do it at this point.

Answer (score 0):

By adding your css parameter as a hidden field in your form.

Then, depending on what you are calling through the form, a GET method would show up all your parameters in the url. If you are submitting as a POST, you can redirect the submition result and appending your css parameter into the URL.